# DrJava - an "Auto Import Claas" error

Tags: java, instructions, drjava

I'm a beginner at Java, when this was added; it gave me ab error, all in this picture! I Compiled then to Interactions  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You have neither a package defined, nor importing any classes. So my best guess is, that your IDE will import this non-existend `Java` class.

Can you try your example in another IDE? i.e. not using "Dr. Java", but [Eclipse for Java Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) might be a good choice.

If you know how to use a terminal (command line), you can also try to compile your class yourself [(Oracle has a tutorial on this)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html):

`javac Hello.java
java Hello`

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked 5 years ago but I encountered this same problem. It happened after Dr Java popped up a message that I needed to update my JRE. I updated my JRE but kept the old versions. Keeping the old versions caused the problem. I updated my JRE again and this time deleted the older versions during the installation process. 
After updating my JRE and deleting the older version, no more problms.